# illegal character error in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am trying to read an excel file using java.  while compiling the program i am getting error as illegal character.  help me to fix this problem.  here is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;



public class Readingexcel {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
         System.out.println("before reading");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("input.xlsx"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("first");

        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;
        String s;

        int rows; // No of rows
        rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
         System.out.println(rows);
         System.out.println(sheet.getRow(1).getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
        int cols = 0; // No of columns
        int tmp = 0;

// This trick ensures that we get the data properly even if it doesn’t start from first few rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 || i < rows; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);

            if (row != null) {
                tmp = sheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();


                if (tmp > cols) {
                    cols = tmp;

                }
            }
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(r);
            if (row != null) {
                for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                    cell = row.getCell((short) c);
                    if (cell != null) {
// Your code here
// s = cell.getData();
                       System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

while compiling the program am getting error like

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
 (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
C:\Documents and Settings\vino>cd C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0_10\bin

C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0_10\bin>javac Readingexcel.java
Readingexcel.java:1: illegal character: \187
∩╗┐import java.io.IOException;
^
Readingexcel.java:1: illegal character: \191
∩╗┐import java.io.IOException;
^
2 errors
```

can anyone help me to fix this problem.

Comment: There are some invisible characters in the beginning of your file. If you can't be bothered to fix them, just copy the source into a new file and delete the old file.

Comment: Looks like you've got `∩╗┐` in your source... What happens when you open your .java file in notepad?

Comment: @L7ColWinters This is a compile-time error, this has nothing to do with input.xlsx.

Comment: Did you cut and pasted the import? maybe there is a unprintable string before import. retype the import somewhere else and delete this line.

Comment: @kristian i tried it but still am getting the error

Comment: @darsha Naturally, if you create a new file and do CTRL+A, then _everything_ gets copied, even the undesired character. Try to copy everything from the second line to the bottom, and rewrite the first line yourself in a new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is BOMs ([Byte Order Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). Make sure you use the correct encoding. Maybe open the file in some other editor and re-save it in order to remove the BOMs. Nodepad ++, for instance, helps you.

Good luck,
Max

Answer (score 4):

What program are you using to edit the source code? It looks like it's inserting a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which javac dislikes. It should be possible to disable the BOM in the editor's settings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a BOM issue. Open your file in a hex editor and remove the first bytes that look strange and come before the first import line.